# How to ignore "invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII" with AptanaStudio Ruby Debugger?

Tags: ruby, winapi

I'm not good English speaker, so please forgive my English problem.

I am using AptanaStudio 3 with Ruby 1.9.2 in Windows 7.
When I try to use Win32 memcpy to get string data from shared memory in ruby debugger, this problem occurs.

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'windows/file_mapping'
require 'windows/msvcrt/buffer'
require 'windows/handle'

include Windows::FileMapping
include Windows::MSVCRT::Buffer
include Windows::Handle

buf1 = 0.chr * 256
@mh = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, false, "TAG_NAME")
@address = MapViewOfFile(@mh, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0)
memcpy(buf1, @address, 256)
UnmapViewOfFile(@address)
CloseHandle(@mh)

puts buf1.unpack("Z*")
```

The problem is below

```
    c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck/rubytypes.rb:151:in `count'
    c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck/rubytypes.rb:151:in `is_binary_data?'
    C:/Users/Zenbook/SkyDrive/AptanaStudio/workspace/best_practice/test.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:112:in `debug_load'
    c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:112:in `debug_program'
    c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/bin/rdebug-ide:87:in `<top (required)>'
    c:/Ruby192/bin/rdebug-ide:19:in `load'
    c:/Ruby192/bin/rdebug-ide:19:in `<main>'
Uncaught exception: invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
```

It doesn't occur when I don't use any breakpoint after memcpy or I just get only string length. I mean, when char string size is 256 ,char string length is 12 and I just get 12 bytes, the problem doesn't occur.

I think this is because debugger cannot read the text from char string including uninitialized place.

So I want to ignore the error or allow string to have invalid text.
Would anyone help me?

Comment: Did you validate that `OpenFileMapping()` and `MapViewOfFile()` are actually succeeding before you read the data? Did you verify that the map view is actually 256 bytes or larger in size before copying from it? Did you verify that the buffer actually contains a null-terminated character string and not something else?

Comment: Yes they are. It happens only in debugger. Without debugger, nothing problem happens. And I made c++ application to set char[256] string in shared memory. It works well. Thank you for your suggestion.